# How to plot multiple clicked points on a Matlab axes?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide

Using `ginput` (or `ginputax`) I ask my user to click on an axes 10 times (for spectrum baseline correction).

My axes is based on a GUIDE GUI.

Essentially this begins like this

```
plot(handles.axes_preview, ppm, xf_base, 'w-', 'LineWidth', 2);

spline_ppm = ginputax(handles.axes_preview, 10);
```

I'd like to plot each click (as `ro`) **as they're being input**, so the user has some feedback of where they clicked.

Any ideas how to code this?

Comment: as soon as you get `[x,y]` from ginput, in the next line, plot them and in the next line put `pause(0.001)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple loop?

```
axis(handles.axes_preview); %// make handles.axes_preview the current axis
hold on
for ii = 1:10
    coords(ii,:) = ginput(1);
    plot(coords(ii,1),coords(ii,2),'ro')
end
```

Also, you may want to add

```
set(handles.axes_preview),'XLimMode','manual');
set(handles.axes_preview),'YLimMode','manual');
```

at the beginning to prevent the axis scale from automatically changing as points are input by the user.

Comment: thanks - with a few minor modifications this worked brilliantly